# Find average change in timeseries

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series

I have an annual mean timeseries dataset for 15 years, and I am trying to find the average change/increase/decrease in this timeseries.

The timeseries I have is spatial (average values for each grid-cell/pixel, years repeat).

How can I do this in R via dplyr?

Sample data

```
year = c(2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008)
Tmean = c(24, 24.5, 25.8,25, 24.8, 25, 23.5, 23.8, 24.8, 25, 25.2, 25.8, 25.3, 25.6, 25.2, 25)
```

Code

```
 library(tidyverse)

df = data.frame(year, Tmean)

    change = df$year %>%
      # Sort by year
      arrange(year) %>%
      mutate(Diff_change = Tmean - lag(Tmean), # Difference in Tmean between years
             Rate_percent = (Diff_change / year)/Tmean * 100) # Percent change # **returns inf values** 
    
    Average_change = mean(change$Rate_percent, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: dplyr and the tidyverse primarily work on data frames, not individual vectors. It's unclear how year and Tmean should go together since Year has 16 elements but Tmean only 15.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add that line, thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the average: `mean()`. To find the differences or changes: `diff()`

So, to find the average change:

```
> avg_change <- mean(diff(Tmean))
> print(avg_change)
[1] 0.06666667
```

If you need that in percentage, then you want to find out how much the difference between an element and its previous one (this year - last year) is in percentage with respect to last year, like so:

```
> pct_change <- Tmean[2:length(Tmean)] / Tmean[1:(length(Tmean)-1)] - 1
> avg_pct_change <- mean(pct_change) * 100
> print(avg_pct_change)
[1] 0.3101632
```

Answer (score 0):

We can put those vectors into a data frame to use with dplyr (...if that's how you want to do it; this is straightforward with base R as well).

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(year, Tmean)
change <- df %>%
  arrange(year) %>%
  mutate(Diff_change = Tmean - lag(Tmean), # Difference in Tmean between years
         Diff_time = year - lag(year),
         Rate_percent = (Diff_change/Diff_time)/lag(Tmean) * 100) # Percent change 

Average_change = mean(change$Rate_percent, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Results (with updated question data)

```
> change
   year Tmean Diff_change Rate_percent
1  2005  24.0          NA           NA
2  2005  24.5         0.5    2.0833333
3  2005  25.8         1.3    5.3061224
4  2005  25.0        -0.8   -3.1007752
5  2006  24.8        -0.2   -0.8000000
6  2006  25.0         0.2    0.8064516
7  2006  23.5        -1.5   -6.0000000
8  2006  23.8         0.3    1.2765957
9  2007  24.8         1.0    4.2016807
10 2007  25.0         0.2    0.8064516
11 2007  25.2         0.2    0.8000000
12 2007  25.8         0.6    2.3809524
13 2008  25.3        -0.5   -1.9379845
14 2008  25.6         0.3    1.1857708
15 2008  25.2        -0.4   -1.5625000
16 2008  25.0        -0.2   -0.7936508
> Average_change
[1] 0.3101632
```

Comment: Apologies, but I just realized that my timeseries is a bit different, so I have the updated the sample data accordingly. Will the above answer still work?

Comment: When I use the above code on the `original dataset`, the `Average_change` value comes out as `NaN`. Maybe this is because, there are `inf` values as well in the `Rate_percent` column.